# Silverlight - working with files

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a Silverlight (Framework 4.0, C# and Visual Studio 2010) application that loads some XML configuration files from the local directory of the application. I need that the code loads all the files in a specific directory.

I'm not able to do it with `System.IO Directory.GetFiles`, how can I do that?

Comment: Please show your code and ask specific questions concerning where you're stuck.

Comment: i dont know why you vote down, i think the question is explicit. Im new in Silverlight, i am not stock in a code. That i need is to load a string[] with files present in a local folder. Local = Server Side files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight code runs in a browser, and you can't "open files locally" at will - when you come to it there are plenty of tutorials available when you search with `silverlight open file` on Bing.

In your case, you seem to want to read files from a server where a Silverlight application is hosted. It is allowed by security restrictions, so make a web request to your origin and get the data. That is, use `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` - that is, see *[Silverlight FlickR Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/04/25/silverlight-flickr-example.aspx)* <sub>(link provided by Alex Golesh @ in [an MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightdeveloper/thread/3a164592-d41d-4c63-9df9-ac5afaa8900a))</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What in fact im doing its working with a plugin on Lync 2010. The Xap its installed on the client machine (so the client and the server are the same pc). Its like a silverlight incrusted on an html incrusted on a webbrowser control on a lync conversation.

Comment: The far away i get with this is:             string[] files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\Languages","*.xml")
                             select file;

Comment: Yeap you re right, there is now way to do want i want. Even more, i can use the web client download but if the file (whatever content, but at least the name file and path) is referenced on the project. There is no way to do something like that dinamically without the security issue. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look for loading files at the client side, use Isolated Storage. This provides a virtual file system that lets you store data such as miscellaneous data, application settings, and entire objects.. more information in *[Isolated Storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-%28silverlight-quickstart%29)*.

If you look for work in the server site, you need is a back-end web service that manages the files and work with and use [MapPath](http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath).